# How Get File Name from URL ,C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, download, webclient, filenames, file-type

How can I get a file name if the address ends with something like this.
`/download/file/36fdd4aebda3819d329640ce75755657bc0c0d4c6811432b3bb6aac321dc78d/ ?`

This is the simplified code example,

```
void geckoWebBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, GeckoNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
             if (e.Uri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/file/"))
                {
                      MyUrl = e.Uri.ToString();
                         // and here I tried different codes construstors, methods but I can not get the filename
                }
            if (e.Uri.Segments[e.Uri.Segments.Length - 1].EndsWith(".exe"))
                {
                       // if the address ended with the FileName this code works well
                       Uri u = new Uri(e.Uri.ToString());
                      string filename = Path.GetFileName(ut.LocalPath);
                       MessageBox.Show(fileName);
                }
     }
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have a "file name", unless there's a [Content-Disposition](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) header, including a filename-parm. It might resemble:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=FileA.abc
```

In that case, the file name would be `FileA.abc`.

---

I've not really worked with the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class, however, and I don't see any easy way to access the headers. You'd have to switch to using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), and do more work yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Content-Disposition should be as

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"abc.msi\""
```

in here you want to get abc.msi. for that you can use following code.

```
            string contentDisposition = resp.Headers["Content-Disposition"];
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition))
            {
                string lookFor = "filename=";
                int index = contentDisposition.IndexOf(lookFor, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                if (index >= 0)
                    fileName = contentDisposition.Substring(index + lookFor.Length).Replace("\"", ""); ;
            }
```