# C# get file name from URL

Tags: c#

How can I download file name from URL ?

Like if I have URL like `http://localhost/?downloadFile=56` and server will return file `example.png`. Because when I try to use

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFileAsync(url, "{FILE-NAME}");
```

I having problem to get the file name automatically.

Comment: If the server returns the file, then haven't you already downloaded the file and its information?

Comment: Can you please correct your question what would you say right now

Comment: If you put an URL like that (with no obvious filename) into a browser address bar, it automatically prompts you to save that file *and suggests you a filename*. I think the question is, how does the browser know, what filename to suggest, and how can you get that filename "manually".

Comment: @Corak Yes that is right I need to get file name as web browsers does.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7293953/1336590

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browsers will use the contents of the `filename` parameter of the `Content-Disposition` header as the default filename. If such a header is not available, browsers will typically use a generated filename based on the final component of the URL's path component.

See some additional information here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/06/07/content-disposition-attachment-and-international-unicode-characters.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd think you'd have to download the file and then get the file name from the downloaded file. Not sure how this is a programming question though.